# How to optimize orientdb query

Tags: java, sql, orientdb

I have two SQL script,like this:

SQL1:

```
select count(*) from (MATCH {class: Dnode, as: snode, where:(name = 'uuid' and value='d8a30901a12d42a17e9050279aebccd2')}.in('Relate'){class: Event, as: event, where:(ts >= 1524844800 and ts <= 1525104000)} RETURN event)
```

SQL2:

```
MATCH {class: Dnode, as: snode, where:(name = 'uuid' and value='d8a30901a12d42a17e9050279aebccd2')}.in('Relate'){class: Event, as: event, where:(ts >= 1524844800 and ts <= 1525104000)} RETURN event
```

I execute SQL1 very slowly, almost up to 2 seconds. And it doesn't use my index  index_1(name,value) on Dnode, and index_2(ts). but I execute the second SQL script, query execute in 0.052 sec,and it use my index.

Comment: orientdv version:  2.2.34

Comment: what kind of index did you define?

Comment: About Event:
index: event_ts_idcooper on('ts','idCooper'),NOTUNIQUE, SBTREE
index: event_ukey on('ei','idCooper'), UNIQUE,SBTREE
About Dnode:
index: dnode_ukey on('name','value') UNIQUE, SBTREE